# JavaScript function returns negative number number of seconds for the user session?

Tags: javascript, jquery, session, twitter-bootstrap-3, timer

I have tried to create JS function that should track user activity and show warning modal box if user is inactive. Function will start on page load. Some variables are global and I use them to set session minutes and keep user activity on the screen. Simply I calculate how much time is user session and subtract number of seconds until warning will show up. If user is active on the page body I keep JS date object stored in global variable. Once timer is down to 0 I reset the time or trigger function that will logout user and redirect to login page. One problem is happening in my code, if user extends the session (Simply clicking on Continue button in modal box) timer should restart and that part works fine. Timer restart count and once reaches 0 warning should show again, instead of that my `expierIn` variable returns negative number. I set any number equal or less than zero to 0. So my session is automatically ended. This is wrong and I'm not sure why second time my math is returning negative number. Here is working example of my code. I haven't included Ajax call that should send ping to the server to keep server side session alive.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    TimeOut(); // Call session timeout function.
});

/*** Start: Session Timeout Handling(The following functions are part of session handling). ***/
var sessionMinutes = 4; // Session time in minutes.
var dmSessionBox; // Session timeout warning box
var lastActivity = null; // keeps track of user last activity
var timeout = null; // keeps timeout value
var secondsToShowDialog = 120; // number of seconds until modal shows on the screen
var dialogShowing = false; // flag to show/hide modal
var nextPoll = false; // flag to set next timeout
var lastHist = new Date(); // first time user logged to the system.
log('lastHit: '+lastHist.toLocaleTimeString());

function TimeOut() {    
    if (sessionMinutes) {
        dmSessionBox = $('<div id="sessiontimeoutwarning" class="modal fade" role="dialog"><div class="modal-dialog modal-lg"><div class="modal-content">    <div class="modal-header"><h2 class="modal-title warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></span>Your session is about to expire</h2></div>    <div class="modal-body"><div class="alert alert-warning warning">           <strong>Warning!</strong>Click the Continue button to extend your session.        </div></div><div class="modal-footer"><button type="button" id="continueButton" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Continue</button</div>/div>/div>/div>');
        $(document.body).append(dmSessionBox);
        
        $('body').on('mousedown keydown', function(event) {
            lastActivity = new Date();
        });

        var sessionSeconds = sessionMinutes * 60; // Convert session minutes in seconds.
        log("Init - session is set to expire in " + sessionSeconds + " seconds at " + new Date(new Date().getTime() + (sessionSeconds*1000)).toLocaleTimeString());
        receiveUpdatedTimeRemaining(sessionSeconds);
    }
}

function receiveUpdatedTimeRemaining(timeout) {
    if (nextPoll)
        clearTimeout(nextPoll);

    var wakeUpMillis;

    if (timeout <= (secondsToShowDialog)) {
        if (!dialogShowing)
            lastActivity !== null ? getTimeout() : showTimeoutDialog(true);

        wakeUpMillis = 30 * 1000; 
    }else{
        showTimeoutDialog(false);
        dialogShowing = false;
        wakeUpMillis = (timeout * 1000) - (secondsToShowDialog * 1000);
    }

    log("receiveUpdatedTimeRemaining - Wake up in " + parseInt(wakeUpMillis/1000) + " for new timeout");
    nextPoll = setTimeout(getTimeout, wakeUpMillis);
}

function getTimeout() {
  clearTimeout(nextPoll);
    var currentTime = new Date().getTime(),
        lastClick = lastActivity !== null ? lastActivity.getTime() : lastHist.getTime(),
        secondsPassed = (currentTime - lastClick) / 1000, // Elapsed number of seconds since last user activity. 
        totalSeconds = sessionMinutes * 60, // Total number of seconds for this session
        expierIn = totalSeconds - secondsPassed;
        log('expierIn: '+expierIn);
  timeout = expierIn <= 0 ? 0 : expierIn; // Set time in timeout variable
    timeout == 0 ? showTimeoutErrorDialog() : receiveUpdatedTimeRemaining(timeout);
    lastActivity = null; // Reset lastActivity
}

function showTimeoutDialog(showIt) {
    dmSessionBox.find('#continueButton').on('click', function() {
        lastActivity = new Date();
        getTimeout();
    });
    showIt ? $('#sessiontimeoutwarning').modal('show') : $('#sessiontimeoutwarning').modal('hide'); 
    dialogShowing = true;
}

function showTimeoutErrorDialog() {
    $('#sessiontimeoutwarning').modal('hide'); // Close modal box
    log('Session timed out.')
}

function log(msg){  
    if (window.console && console.log) 
        console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString() + " :: " + msg); 
}
/*** End: Session timeout handling. ***/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Session Timeout Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>My App</div>
</body>
</html>
```

After warning shows and I click continue session will extend for another 240 seconds and wakeup call to warning is set to 120 seconds but instead of showing the modal session will end. I'm not sure if my variable is not overwriting previous value or something else is wrong in my code.

Comment: Please use `if` blocks instead of unassigned ternaries, like `timeout == 0 ? showTimeoutErrorDialog() : receiveUpdatedTimeRemaining(timeout)`, that is *not* clever, your code is very hard to read/understand.

Comment: @James I'm not sure why if/else block is better than ternary operator? How difficult is to ready that specific line of code?

Comment: @espresso_coffee I believe the comment is more about using the ternary for logical branching instead of its intended use of assignment since it returns a value, and not its readability.  It's generally frowned upon to use it for logical code branching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found all the script more complicated than needed, and decided to show a simplified solution.

This version simply restart the timer at mouse or key activity, and if none within the first set timeout, it shows a warning message and restart the timer, and after the second, it shows a logged out message and unbind the mouse/key events.

From here you can add your own modal dialog back, pinging server etc.

*Updated with a "time stamp" variable, so the call to the server doesn't occur too often.*

Stack snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    TimeOut();
    $('body').on('mousedown keydown', function(event) {
        TimeOut();
    });
});

var TimeOut = (function(t,ts) {
  function startTimeOut() {
    // clear any warnings etc.
    document.body.innerHTML = 'My App<br>';
    if (t) {
      clearTimeout(t);
    }
    t = setTimeout(timedWarn, 5000);

    // set a time stamp and check when to ping server
    if (ts) {      
      var ct = new Date().getTime();
      //call server every e.g. 12 sec. and reset time stamp
      if ( (ct - ts) / 1000 > 12 ) {
        // sendPing();
        ts = new Date().getTime();
        console.log('send ping');
      } 
    } else {
      ts = new Date().getTime();
    }
        
  }
  function timedWarn() {
    t = setTimeout(timedOut, 5000);
    // show warn dialog
    document.body.innerHTML += 'Because of inactivity you are about to be logged out.'
  }
  function timedOut() {
    // logout, redirect
    document.body.innerHTML = 'Logged out';
    
    // unbind is not needed if a redirect is made
    $('body').unbind('mousedown keydown');
  }
  return (function() {
    startTimeOut();
  });
})();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Session Timeout Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  My App<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I looked over your code and it is very simple. Only difference you are showing up the dialog when user should be already logged out. Dialog box should show 60 or 120 seconds before session expires. That will give an option to the user to extend their session if they want to. That part is missing in your example.

Comment: In your code can we use elapse time instead of Confirm JS? So if user clicks continue we automatically extend the session.

Comment: @espresso_coffee I updated my answer. Now it use 2 timers, one for warning, one for logout.

Comment: I saw you updated answer. One more question, why do you use unbind if session is timed out? Thank you.

Comment: @espresso_coffee It actually only need one timer, so I updated it again.

Comment: @espresso_coffee I used unbind here, since I don't redirect to another page, as if not, one could simply click the page and it restarted the timers. You don't need that of course, and I added a note in the script about it.

Comment: Everything seemed fine until I was trying to find the best place to set AJAX call that will send ping to the server to keep session alive. If I put AJAX function in `startTimeOut()` function that will send the ping every time user interact with the page. At the same time if I put AJAX in `timedWarn()` that might cause the problem. User can keep resting time out but not sending ping to the server  before session timeout expire on server side. My concern is that if I put AJAX in on `startTimeOut()` that will have way to many ajax calls to the server. Please elt me know your thoughts on this.

Comment: My old code might be too complex but it was checking time from the last activity and then sending ajax call to the server. Your code will reset any time user clicks,type on the screen.

Comment: @espresso_coffee I added a _time stamp_ to my solution. With this you can control how often you want to make the server call.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166829/discussion-between-espresso-coffee-and-lgson).